# Response Email Won`t Sent

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to make automatic newsletter reply using codeigniter.

```
     public function response() 
    {
    $status             = $this->uri->segment(3);           
    $id                 = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $id_user            = $this->uri->segment(5);

    $data['id']         = $id;
    $data['status']     = $status ;

   $this->messages_model->pending($data); <<<<update database

   $this->load->library('email');

   $config['protocol']  = 'smtp';           
   $config['smtp_host']    = 'host.org';            
   $config['smtp_port'] = 'secretport';         
   $config['smtp_user'] = 'from_email@example.com';          
   $config['smtp_pass'] = 'examplepassword';        
   $config['smtp_timeout']  = '100';        
   $config['mailtype']      = 'html';         
   $config['charset']       = 'utf-8';              
   $config['newline']       = "\r\n";       

    if($status == "approved") {
    $message='your form is approved';
    redirect("/response/approved");
           }else{
    $message='your form is approved';
    redirect("/response/rejected");
       }         
         $to_email = $this->messages_model->reply($id_user);

         $this->email->initialize($config);
         $this->email->from('blablabla@email.com', 'NAME');
         $this->email->to($to_email);
         $this->email->subject('Confirmation Note'); 
         $this->email->message($message);
     }
```

It's updating database succesfully,but no email on my inbox.

Is something wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in CI docs for the redirect function:

> This function will terminate script execution

Reference: [Redirect function](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=redirect#redirect)

So first, move the redirects to the end of the function.

Second, after you set all the email properties, user $this->email->send() to actually send the email.

Reference: [Email library](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/email.html#sending-email)

Third, your reject message is wrong :)

Update to question in the comment:

```
 $to_email = $this->messages_model->reply($id_user);
 $this->email->initialize($config);
 $this->email->from('blablabla@email.com', 'NAME');
 $this->email->to($to_email);
 $this->email->subject('Confirmation Note'); 


if ($status == "approved") {
    $message='your form is approved';
    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();
    redirect("/response/approved");
} else {
    $message='your form is rejected';
    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();
    redirect("/response/rejected");
}
```

Comment: so i have to initialize two times inside IF function ?

Comment: No, you can initialize once, before the IF, and only place the $this->email->message($message) and $this->email->send() inside the IF.

Comment: Added an example in the answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to put redirected code after email section .

```
     $to_email = $this->messages_model->reply($id_user);

         $this->email->initialize($config);
         $this->email->from('blablabla@email.com', 'NAME');
         $this->email->to($to_email);
         $this->email->subject('Confirmation Note'); 
         $this->email->message($message);
         $this->email->send();
         if($status == "approved") {
              $message='your form is approved';
              redirect("/response/approved");
         }else{
              $message='your form is approved';
              redirect("/response/rejected");
         }
```

Comment: nah, $message='blablabla'; have to run before $this->email->message($message);